# Returning a variable as an inputs value doesn't close properly with a double quote

Tags: php, string, variables, return

This code is returning an input who's value is the $value variable

```
$value = "Analytics: \r\n\r\n --------------------------------------------\r\n";
$value .= "Campaign Source: ".$campaign_source."\r\n";
$value .= "Campaign Name: ".$campaign_name."\r\n";
$value .= "Campaign Medium: ".$campaign_medium."\r\n";
$value .= "Campaign Term: ".$campaign_term."\r\n";
$value .= "Campaign Content: ".$campaign_content."\r\n\r\n";
$value .= "First visit: ".$first_visit."\r\n";
$value .= "Previous visit: ".$previous_visit."\r\n";
$value .= "Current visit: ".$current_visit_started."\r\n";
$value .= "Times visited: ".$times_visited;

if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

$name = $tag['name'];
if (empty($name)) return '';

// add the value to the form's hidden input 
$html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="'. $value .'"/>'; 

return $html;
```

The last string in the $html variable `"/>` isn't closing correctly in the rendered HTML and looks like some other type of double quote. You see in the image attached the double quote at the end of the input isn't recognized, and it's using the ending quote of the opening span tag. I tried replacing the $value variable in the $html variable with another single variable such as $times_visited and it rendered correctly. I think all the strings going into $value is throwing it off some how. Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The string that you are passing to $value and entering it in input tag has single/double quotes that are breaking everything.

Comment: @BhavikShah are you suggesting that I change the double quotes used in the $value string to single quotes?

Comment: You're putting a value with line breaks and `<br />`s into the `value` attribute of an `<input>` element?  Why?

Comment: @JLRishe It's how the developer wrote their plugin, it's value is sent in a form so the line breaks are used for formatting, and they stuffed them all into one inputs value

Comment: No. What i am saying is that $value has some single/double quotes. Try echo $value only and check. It must have some quotes in it. I took your code and removed the $campaign_* variables and other variables that you have used to prepare $value. It worked. This makes it clear that $campaign_* variables and other variables that you have used to prepare $value has some quotes that break your normal HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will never work with a `input`. Even if you don't have any issue with the double quotes I don't think a value with newlines and `<br>` tags will work as an input value. You should either use a `"<textarea style='display:none' name=\"name\">$value</textarea>"` or use one `<input>` for each of the values you want to pass as hidden.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking to setup an individual input for each value.